# V8 function execution interruption

Tags: c++, v8

**Hi**. I want to implement **terminateThread** function in JavaScript (same clearTimeout).
I implemented **startThread** function which starts new win32 thread, which calls function. Function can execute infinitely and I need opportunity to stop the function execution, but don't stop execution main thread (don't use isolate->TerminateExecution).
I tried to find source code of clearInterval and clearTimeout functions in WebApi, but it was unsuccessfull.
How can I interrupt V8 function execution from another thread?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Given that only one thread can be active in an isolate at a time, `isolate->TerminateExecution()` would appear to be the right way to interrupt the *currently executing* thread. You can discard the termination request afterwards, so that other threads can resume their execution.

Remember: it is your responsibility as an embedder of V8 to make sure that there is never more than one thread running in a given Isolate. You will get weird crashes otherwise. You can use `v8::Locker` to achieve this, or your own locking/mutex solution.

Comment: Explain please. Where I must call isolate->TerminateExecution()?
My second thread can't call it because second thread called v8::Function::Call.
As I know, if I call isolate->TerminateExecution() in main thread, the main thread will terminate execution too.
Maybe I don't understand how does isolate->TerminateExecution() work?
In V8 docs about TerminateExecution function:
"Forcefully terminate the current thread of JavaScript execution in the given isolate."

Example of code in C++:
https://pastebin.com/ev45ZY7V

Example of code in JavaScript:
https://pastebin.com/hXrc16z0

Comment: Say thread A is running JavaScript code in the isolate. Call `isolate->TerminateExecution` from thread B (which is not executing any thing in the same isolate). That creates a special kind of uncatchable exception that makes thread A's execution return to the embedder, i.e. to your code. You can then do whatever you like, e.g. call `isolate->CancelTerminateExecution`, get out of the Locker, terminate thread A, and let thread B continue. V8 will not stop any `std::thread`s for you.

Comment: I tested it. I understand that TerminateExecution terminates currently execution thread(I thought that this function terminates all threads which use isolate).
I wrote function for terminate current thread.
`void TerminateCurrentThread(const v8::FunctionCallbackInfo<v8::Value>& args) { args.GetIsolate()->TerminateExecution(); }`
It's work. But I need call this function from other execution thread, so I must create thread.
But in new thread I must check that current thread is thread, which I want to terminate.
How can I do it? Maybe some function `GetCurrentExecutionThreadId`?

Comment: I'd recommend that you keep track of threads in your code: you are in control of which thread enters an Isolate at which time, so you can add any bookkeeping that you need. If you want multiple background threads active at the same time, you'll need multiple Isolates. Or you can have a global mutex, so all your threads time-share the same Isolate; in that case you can easily keep track of which thread is currently executing in there.